# How to list all folders on a server with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs, directory-listing

On my webserver i have several directories with files in them like:

- afolder/file.xml
- anotherfolder/file.xml
- stillanother/file.xml

The files contain information about some locations I want to show on a Map (with openlayers) so I need the files in JS. The problem is that i don't know what the folders are called and how many of them are there , so I need a list of them.

I need something like this:

```
for each (folder as f)
    map.showLocations(f/file.xml)
```

How could this be done ?

I searched for the solution but all i found was about files and folders on client side.
I am using prototype js and it is possible to use PHP.

Comment: That's a bit dangerous. You don't really want your browsers to be searching server directories. Why  not have a web service that returns all the files?

Comment: you're going to want to do this in php, rather than javascript.  JS runs on the client, your files are on the server.

Comment: You're running JavaScript on your server?

Comment: Well if i would now how than i could use php for that, but i have to use JS to paint the Position on the Map. Every folder is a user and the files contain the position of the user. I want to iterate over the folders and paint all positions of all users.

Comment: can't be done from client-side javascript.

Comment: Maybe the question is a bit unprecise. Its not problem for me to use php, but i dont know how to connect the result from php with the javascript.

Comment: ahh, alright, that's easier. hold on.

Comment: @JHnet Just have JavaScript code do an Ajax request to a server-side PHP script which gets, and returns the info.

Comment: You can output the result from the PHP into the document as a hidden layer or even directly inject it into the JavaScript. Ajax is always an option too.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Ok than i change my question to : "How to do an ajax request to server-side php which gets and returns the info to javascript ?" Any tutorial oder something else for this ?

Comment: @JHnet Read the official prototype.js documentation here: http://prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you list your directories in a PHP variable `$directories`, you can `echo` to the page something like

```
echo '<script>var Directories = '.json_encode($directories).';</script>';
```

now you have inside your page a javascript variables which you can iterate over and do your magic

```
for (dir in Directories) {
  map.showLocations(Directories[dir]/file.xml);
}
```

Another option is to have an AJAX request to do it for you (I am using jQuery for this example because I don't know prototype bu it should be roughly the same)

```
$.getJSON('directories.php', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    map.showLocations(value+'/file.xml');
  });
});
```

and your PHP code should be something like this

```
<?php
  *** iterate over the directories and save them into an array ***
  echo json_encode($directories);
  exit();
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I never used ajax before, but there's always a first time :) Have to check the prototype doc for exakt syntax but thank you for the general approach !

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this about 2 hours ago for my job. I used a [jQuery plugin from A Beautiful Site called jQuery File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/).

If you're just looking to get the data into JavaScript, then this UI plugin may be overkill, but it contains the source code that will return JSON containing a list of paths, which you can get by calling a jQuery.ajax request.

**JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        dir : '/your_directory'
    }
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'getDirectories.php',
    success: function(d) {
        //do something with the data 
        console.dir(d.directories); //d.directories will be an array of strings
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
//return a JSON object with directories
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I never used ajax before, but there's always a first time :) Have to check the prototype doc for exakt syntax but thank you for the general approach !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PrototypeJS version of what everyone else is talking about

```
new Ajax.Request('getdirectories.php',{
    method : 'post',
    onSuccess : function(result){
        //result.responseJSON is the JSON object
        var dirs = result.responseJSON;

        dirs.each(function(item){
            map.showLocations(item+'/file.xml');
        });
    });
```